# jquery validation plugin displaying error message in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am using ASP.NET MVC4. I have **maxLength** attribute defined on **input** element. when the form is submitted in **Firefox, Chorme or IE 10** successfully. While in **IE9 or IE8** it performs the an unwanted validation and gives the following error message with the text box.

**"Please enter no more than 6 characters.".**

This error message comes from jQuery validation document (**jquery.validate-vsdoc.js**). But why is it occurring on IE9/IE8 and not on other browsers?.

I have tried updating this document to the latest version, but no luck.

Thanks,
-Imran

Comment: Which jquery version are you including?

Comment: vsdoc is generally for documentation of jquery libarary provided by Microsoft team(for intelligence in visual studio to work). the problem is somewhere else. Which jquery verison are u using? make sure its the latest one.

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.8.20. I have this problem only in IE9 and IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know which html version you are using .
If you are using html 5 then check is there property set in html declaration like maxlength.if it is there just remove it